# Не работает условие if в цикле foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь вывести картинку к таксономии, и, в случае ее отсутствия, выводить `photo_none`.
Почему-то в приведенном ниже примере значение 'imgtax' выводится независимо от empty, а когда поле `imgtax` содержит любое значение, выводится `"value=imgtax+photo_none.jpg" (img src="/wp-content/uploads/actor1125.jpgphoto_none.jpg")`:

```
function tax_img() {

$cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'actors' );

foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
    echo '<span><img src="';
    if (empty(the_field( 'imgtax', $cur_term ))) {
        echo 'photo_none.jpg'; }
    echo '"/>';
    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( (int)$cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a></span><br>';
}

}
```

В настройках поля imgtax выбрано Image URL

Comment: Как минимум в `else echo "the_field( 'imgtax', $cur_term )";` кавычки лишние.

Comment: это не играет никакой роли

Comment: возможно есть смисл поставить xdebug и смотреть что именно возвращает функция the_field?

Comment: нет такой возможности.
даже если я напишу там 
     else echo 'Здесь был Василий Пупкин!';
смысл вопроса не изменится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, вот что мне требовалось сделать:

```
$cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'actors' );

foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){

    echo '<span><img src="';

    if($img = get_field( 'img-tax', $cur_term )) {
        echo $img;
    } else {
        echo 'photo_none.jpg';
    }

    echo '"/>';
    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( (int)$cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a></span><br>';
}
```

Comment: А почему не присвоить значение переменной $img вне if а потом уже делать проверку? Так же легче читается

Answer (score 0):

Строка

```
 } else echo "the_field( 'imgtax', $cur_term )";
```

должна выглядеть так

```
 } else the_field( 'imgtax', $cur_term );
```

В [настройках поля](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) `imgtax` должно быть выбрано `Image URL`

Comment: это не важно, код обрабатывается что с echo что без него одинаково

Comment: @csr-z не читатель?  Репопонижатель помогающих? Ну-ну..

Comment: у меня нет возможности изменять вашу репутацию, если вы об этом

Comment: Вы чушь-то не порите. Echo с двойными кавычками выведет строку символов внутри двойных кавычек. Именно это я исправил.

Comment: при чем тут условие в else вообще? ваша правка необходима была лишь вам. именно об этом я и написал. читайте вопрос, перед тем как отвечать на него.

Comment: Для the_field echo не нужен, echo нужен для get_field, что и было исправлено, ну и кавычки лишние

Comment: @eugene_v вы посмотрите вопрос ДО правки, я на него отвечал. Обожаю таких ТС, которые после ответа правят вопрос, причем так, что весь смысл меняется.

Comment: Так, я же ничего и не говорю, я внимательно посмотрел ответ и понял, что автор поправил вопрос, убрав изначальную проблему, но просто дописал о echo, т.к. в будущем возможно это ему пригодится, чтоб не допускать такую же ошибку

Comment: в данном случае суть вопроса такова, что значение поля выводится вне зависимости от наличия if в цикле. я не знаю, как правильно построить условие, потому и задал вопрос, а вовсе не для того, чтобы меня учили, как echo писать, с кавычками или без. но спасибо за информацию, учту. хотя к сути она отношения не имеет.